# PHP: "Submit" box

Tags: php, html

I am fairly new to PHP and am having trouble with an assignment. The assignment is to create a simple address book in PHP, and i would like my address book to display all addresses that are in it along with a submission box at the bottom to add more addresses. Currently, I can get the addresses to display, but the submission box gives me an error ") Notice: Undefined variable: addres_add in C:\wamp64\www\address_tmp\address.php on line 18"

This is my code thus far, I snagged the submission box code from another answer here on StackOverflow, but I don't know how to modify it to fit my needs.

```
<?php
//Open address book file and print to user
$fh = fopen("address_book.txt", "r+");
echo file_get_contents("address_book.txt");

//Perfom submit function
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_END);
    fwrite($fh, "$addres_add") or die("Could not write to file");
    fclose($fh);
    print("Address added successfully. Updated book:<br /><br />");
    echo file_get_contents("address_book.txt");
{
$var = $_POST['any_name'];
}
?>
<?php
//HTML for submission box?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="any_name">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form> 

<p>
```

Comment: I can't see `$addres_add` being declared

Comment: Don't they teach such basic things before giving you assignments?

Answer (score 2):

You never assigned the variable from the form input. You need:

```
$addres_add = $_POST['any_name'];
fwrite($fh, "$addres_add") or die("Could not write to file");
```

Also, if you're just adding to the file, you should open it in `"a"` mode, not `"r+"`. Then you don't need to seek to the end, that happens automatically.

You probably should put a newline between each record of the file, so it should be:

```
fwrite($fh, "$addres_add\n") or die("Could not write to file");
```

Otherwise, all the addresses will be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version of your program.

```
<?php

$file_path ="address_book.txt";

// Extract the file contents as a string
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file_path);
if ($file_contents) // Check if the file opened correctly
    echo($file_contents . " \n"); // Echo contents (added newline for readability)
else
    echo("Error opening file. \n");

// Make sure both form fields are set
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['any_name']))
{
    // Append the new name (used the newline character to make it more readable)
    $file_contents .= $_POST["any_name"] ."\n";
    // Write the new content string to the file
    file_put_contents($file_path, $file_contents);
    print("Address added successfully. Updated book:<br /><br />");
    echo($file_contents);
}
else
{
    echo("Both form elements must be set. \n");
}

?>
    //HTML for submission box?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="any_name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Even with no comments it should be self explanatory. I leave the proper error dealing to you.

To answer your question, the error was being caused because the $address_add variable wasn't previously declared. You also added quotes to it, making it a string.

Comment: @alex_HG Thanks a bunch for the help, I have one more question regarding this, when entering in a name and address into the submission box, how would I have it formatted in the file the same as the rest of the addresses? For example:
First Last<br />
Street Address<br />
Town, State, zipcode<br /><br />

Currently I can only get the whole address to appear on one line with a break after that.

Comment: You have to add more inputs and process the data in the same way the any_name variable was processed, then just append it to the string using escape characters to make it more readable. For example '\t' will add a tab to the string.